# Create child page within custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, child-pages

I want to be able to have a link like this, **site.com/my-custom-type-slug/single-custom-post-name/stats/**, where **/stats** should contain the **/my-custom-type-slug** page content and when I add content to the **/stats** page, it should be added after the parent's content.

The **/stats** page should be available for every page created within my CPT, for example **/my-custom-type-slug2**, **/my-custom-type-slug3**, and so on, to have the **/stats**.

I'm thinking that a solution can be to create a page named **stats** and assign a custom template, but the problem is how can I create the additional content for every new post which I'm creating?

This would be easy if I didn't need the comments to be activated because I was doing it like this:

Add a custom WYSIWYG field inside my posts with [ACF](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/wysiwyg-editor/) plugin, then create an endpoint:

```
function wpa121567_rewrite_endpoints(){
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'stats', EP_PERMALINK );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpa121567_rewrite_endpoints' );
```

After this my URL would look like this:
`site.com/your-custom-type-slug/single-custom-post-name/stats/`

Then in my `single-{cpt}.php` template I can check if the request is for **stats**, and include or output the desired data:

```
if( array_key_exists( 'stats', $wp_query->query_vars ) ){
    // the request is for the comments page
} 
else {
    // the request is for the main post
}
```

This solution is not working for me because I can't activate comments on **/stats** because I'm using an endpoint to create it.

As a conclusion, what I need is two separate sets of comments for both the parent and "/stats" page. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a hierarchical custom post type and a conditional to create an additional loop on your `single-{cpt}.php`. By using hierarchical custom post type, you can create a **sub-cpt** , like a **sub page** as the **stats** part of it's parent post.

The **sub-cpt** then can be used to store additional data (e.g. in post_content or custom_fields) and also the comment specific to the **stats** part of the post.

Note that you will need to include only parent cpt (excluding the sub cpt) on the main loop using the `pre_get_posts` hook.

On the `single-{cpt}.php` it should be something like this

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php if( array_key_exists( 'stats', $wp_query->query_vars ): ?>

        <!-- output the data for the stats part -->
        <?php
            // query sub cpt data
            $args = array(
                'post_parent' => $post->ID,
                'post_type'   => 'your-cpt', 
                'posts_per_page' => 1,
                'post_status' => 'any'
            );

            $sub_cpt = get_children( $args);

            // query sub cpt comment
            $args = array(
                'post_id' => $sub_cpt->ID,
            );

            $child_post_comment = get_comments( $comment_args );
        ?>

    <?php else: ?>

        <!-- output the data as you intended for the non stats part -->
        <?php the_title(); ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php
            // query sub cpt comment
            $args = array(
                'post_id' => $post->ID,
            );
        ?>
        <?php get_comments( $args ); ?>

    <?php endif; ?> 
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```